# I am trying to make a Discord bot that boosts your server every two hours

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So what I am trying to do is when the bot is added into your Discord server the bot says "!d bump" exactly every two hours? This is what I have so far

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
 const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
 });

client.on('message', msg => {
 if (msg.content === 'ping') {
 msg.reply('pong');
 }
 });

 client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '*invite') {
  msg.reply('invite');
  }
  });



client.login('token');
```

EDIT: Also, I am not userbotting and this is a problem because I can't get the bot to only say the phrase and not pinging someone

Comment: What is the problem you are having and what is the expected result?

Comment: @Tarazed I am trying to get it to say the command every 2 hours but I can't get the bot to just say the command without replying to someone

Comment: @user12677280 You're trying to get your bot to activate another bot? 95% of bots ignore other bot messages by default. Unless you're userbotting I guess?

Comment: @Klaycon No I'm not UserBotting. I didn't know that. How would you userbot though?

Comment: @user12677280 Userbotting will just get you banned by Discord so I wouldn't recommend it. It's explicitly forbidden by their TOS.

Comment: Hi @user12677280, welcome! It would be helpful to edit your post with the detail you added in a comment above regarding what you are trying to achieve and what the problem you currently have is. The more detail you provide the more likely it is that someone will be able to help you :)

Comment: @Klaycon Ai I did not know that either

Comment: @Ashley ok i will do that

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated in the comments, bots are often ignored by other bots and as such the sent command will be ignored.

But here's a possible approach using [setInterval or setTimeout](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval):

```js
function sendBump() {
  const channels = ...; // Fetch the channels you want to send the message to

  // Few different types of loops, choose the one must suitable/you know best

  channel.send('!d bump');
}

client.on('ready', () => {
  setInterval(() => sendBump(), 7200000); // Call the method every two hours
});
```